# how to set precision in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

In C++, there is a std::setprecision function can set float/double precision.
 how can i set precision in Objective-C? and this print below:

```
(lldb) p 10/200
(int) $0 = 0
(lldb) p (float)10/200
(float) $1 = 0.0500000007
```

line 3 result is 0.0500000007, why is '7' in the result? how can i get the result is 0.05?

Comment: chek my answer.

Comment: You are confusing the debugger with the programming language. And before you get too disappointed, check what std::setprecision actually does. And since you are looking at the debugger, you definitely don't want to change what you see, because that could only hide bugs.

Comment: [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 2):

Floating-point numbers are *binary* floating-point numbers. 0.05 cannot be represented exactly by a binary floating point number. The result cannot ever be exactly 0.05.

In addition, you are quite pointlessly using float instead of double. float has only six or seven digits precision. Unless you have a very good reason that you can explain, use double, which gives you about 15 digits of precision. You still won't be able to get 0.05 exactly, but the error will be much less.

Answer (score 0):

You may use NSNumberFormatter to format objects in a wide variety of ways --- too numerous to list here, see the documentation available from Xcode.  Also see the Data Formatting Guide.

Answer (score 0):

You must make change between `%` `modulo` operator and its `identifier` `f` in order to get desired result.

```
NSString* formattedNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", myFloat];
```

%.02f tells the formatter that you will be formatting a float (%f) and, that should be rounded to two places, and should be padded with 0s.

Example:

```
%f = 25.000000    // results 25.000000 
%.f = 25    // results 25
%.02f = 25.00 // results 25.00
```

Comment: Do not use `stringWithFormat`. Use an `NSNumberFormatter` so the number is formatter properly in the user's locale.

Answer (score -1):

plz use

```
     double A =  0.0500000007;
       NSString *b =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%.02f",A] ;
   double B = [b doubleValue];
```

Comment: Please don't. If you are putting numbers into labels, use a formatter that supports localization.

Comment: @Sulthan he need result in  0.05. what wrong in this.

Comment: For many people, the result should be `0,05` or some other appropriate format. Use `NSNumberFormatter` to format numbers appropriate for the user's locale.